# Theory of Computation: How to determine what language a DFA accepts

Tags: math, theory, computation-theory

[dfa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX6BB.jpg)

So I have an assignment to find out which language this dfa accepts.

I found many different words that the DFA accepts for example:

```
w1=0
w2=101
w3=1111
w4=100011
w5=11001
```

So my problem is that I can find many words but I dont see a pattern with which I can determine the Language.

I figured out that if the word contains a single 1 i cant be accepted.
That if the word is in q0 there can follow as many 0 and it will still be accepted.

I dont want the answer which language it may accept, I want to know how the way is to find this out.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to cs.stackexchange.com where computer science questions are answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed by cases. You know that if a word is accepted, it must either be empty or ultimately come from `q2`, which means it must end in `1`. But if you are in `q2`, you have previously come from either `q1` or `q3`. If you come from q1 (the word ends in X01), you have two options: either you come from `q0` (so the word ends in `0*101`), or you come from `q3`, which means the word ends in (`X001`). I indicate with `X` what we still don't know about how the word begins. I'm sure you are capable of continuing this reasoning by cases and you will probably be able to enumerate all the accepted sequences in this way.